# Mysql structure of forum websites

Tags: mysql

I was building a forum website but I could not decide how to create Mysql structure of it. Just like in here, a user asks lots of questions and users answer them many times and none of them is overwriten if they answer more. So, would i create a table for questions and answers table for forum websites. Would not they be overwriten if i create just one table for questions and answers table for each user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User Table:

```
user_id (int, auto_increment)
username (varchar)
password (varchar, 32 (md5))
email (varchar (to recover password))
```

Forum Table:

```
forum_id (int, auto_increment)
forum_title (varchar)
forum_category (int)
```

Forum Subcategory:

```
forum_subcat_id (int, auto_increment)
forum_id (int)
forum_subcat_title (varchar)
forum_subcat_description (text)
```

Forum Threads:

```
thread_id (int, auto_increment)
thread_title (varchar)
thread_body (text, regular thread format)
forum_subcategory (int, where it belongs)
posted_by (int, the user that posts the thread)
posted_on (int, timestamp of the time the thread was posted)
```

Comment Table:

```
comment_id (int, auto_increment)
comment_body (text, comment text)
thread_id (int)
commented_by (int, user_id)
comment_time (int, timestamp of the time the comment was posted)
```

just giving you a broad idea what it should look like, of course you can add more features like rating system, polls etc.

Answer (score 0):

That's why you wouldn't create just one table for both questions and answers.  Instead, you'd have two tables.  For example:

```
Question
========
question_id
question_text
```

and

```
Answer
======
answer_id
user_id
question_id
date_answered
answer_text
```

Of course, user_id above implies yet another table for containing users.